# rotate and repeat image using xml

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

I want to set background image with rotation and repeating the background image.

For repeating

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:src="@drawable/border"
android:tileMode="repeat" />
```

For rotation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:fromDegrees="90"
    android:toDegrees="90"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:drawable="@drawable/border">
```

Now I want to combine this code in one drawable and want to use as background

I'm trying like this but not working

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:tileMode="repeat" >

   <rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
      android:fromDegrees="90"
      android:toDegrees="90"
      android:pivotX="50%"
      android:pivotY="50%"
      android:drawable="@drawable/border">
</rotate>

</bitmap>
```

Comment: you will probably need a custom Drawable, i dont think it can be done in xml only

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use a custom view. I also tried that for my animated background. Just use thread, handler and canvas.scale() method for rotating the view background. And one thing i wanna ask. Whats the need of setting as background? You can set the rotating drawable as a background view and do the other things on the view above with transparent background.

Comment: I have border image that is divided into two parts. one part of is corner image another part for middle part of two corner that is repeating image

Comment: hi @JatinMalwal i want same result but no luck...can you please provide any code...you can find my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38890063/android-graphics-camera-rotation-scaling-my-image

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="-45"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%">

    <bitmap 
        android:alpha=".5"
        android:src="@drawable/image"
        android:tileMode="repeat" />
</rotate>
```

Comment: Can one specify the size or scale in the same file?

Comment: @rraallvv You can enclose <bitmap> tag inside <item> tag and item you can specify android:width and android:height